# QT/QML renderig - bad quality

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml

I have a problem with QML rendering. As you can see on screen below, QML create window in bad quality. If I try to use QML animation, program will stop. It's strange because it happened only of few computers in my company.
Program was tested on Windows XP, 7 and 10 and problem is on XP and 7.
Program was written with QT5.
It could be a OpenGL or DirectX problem?

[Bad quality QML gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO3nz.jpg)

Here is screen from corect working program:

[Good quality QML gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8vy7.jpg)

Comment: It's probably a driver issue. Have a look on the bug tracker for similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for my problem I found on QT forum. I had to change QCore attribute

`// Options on Windows; set before instantiating QApplication
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute( Qt::AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL ); // use Software OpenGL`